# CODEIGNITER - Nginx config can read subfolder but not uri in subfolder?

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

Here my config.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    break;
}

#proxy_cache_path /usr/local/nginx/cache  levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m i$
include  mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
gzip  on;


root /var/www/domain.com/html;
index  index.php index.html;

location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
}

location /x {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /x/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ ^/(images|js|css)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}

location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        root  /images;
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    break;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

I try figure it whole day.

It can be access `domain.com/x/ or domain.com/x/index.php`
but cannot be access `domain.com/x/welcome` or `domain.com/x/index.php/welcome`

### FLOW

domain.com = codeigniter framework

domain.com/x = codeigniter framework

Mostly i try using `try_files` also not success,
even i try this one also cannot success
`rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;`

Please refer to location/x

Comment: You have `if (!-e $request_filename)`  that rewrites `/x/welcome` to `/index.php?//x/welcome`

Comment: I success to access with https://domain.com/x/index.php?/welcome/test

how to remove index.php? without interupt domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Just remove to make uri success to access

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
break;
}
```